# How to click an ng show element with dynamic id using selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I click on an ng show element with dynamic id using selenium, the element looks like the one below:

```
<i ng-show="courseDetails.lmstype !='3rdParty' &amp;&amp; courseContentLevel.levelName != 'Pre-Requisite' &amp;&amp; courseContentLevel.levelName != 'End of Course'" class="fa fa-plus-circle font-20 pointer-cursor margin-right-25" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu40282cf567bbb4d00167c117ccbb016b" ng-class="{'margin-right-25' : courseContentLevel.levelName == 'Course Outcome'}"></i>
::before == $0
</i>
```

Here the id keeps on changing everytime, so I cannot rely on the By.id to click that.
If I plan to go after the xpath of it, that too comes like:

```
//*[@id="dropdownMenu40282cf567bbb4d00167c117ccbb016b"]
```

that too based on the id I hope, which is also of no use it seems.

Kindly give some other workaround here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By.cssSelector() did the trick for me !                   Other options playing with xpath like starts-with, contains, etc didn't work for me.

Comment: If in case someone encounters the same scenario, the answer in my case is:    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.cb-sideBar:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(3) > i:nth-child(1)")).click();

Comment: Keep in mind that that could stop working if the structure of the HTML changes. The more accurate way - in my opinion - of locating that webelement would be something like this: driver.findElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'i') and contains(@ng-show, 'courseDetails')]"))